# How to pass document to updateDocument method of DocuSign Java SDK

Tags: java, docusignapi

I'm relatively new to using DocuSign and I'm trying to send emails using it.

I want to create and update envelopes in DocuSign using the Java SDK.

I'm able to create an envelope using templateId and now I want to replace one of the documents in the envelope using documentId.

I'm able to do it using the rest api as documented [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/update/). It says that the document body is sent as the request body. And the SDK method mentioned in the documentation for this is `Envelopes::updateDocument`.

But when I tried using the SDK, `updateDocument` takes only three parameters, the signature is

> public void updateDocument(String accountId, String envelopeId, String documentId) throws ApiException {...}

So how do we pass the document body using the SDK in order to update a document in an envelope ?

Comment: Have you tried updateList
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/updatelist/

Answer (score 1):

An approach that works is to define your document, add your document to an envelopeDefinition and then call the updateDocuments method passing your envelopeDefintion.

```
    public static String AddDocument(ApiClient apiClient, String envelopeId, String accountId, String docPath)
    {
        try {
            
        String retVal;
        EnvelopesApi api = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);

        //******************* Add Document*********************
        ArrayList documents = new ArrayList<Document>();
        byte[] fileBytes = null;
        Document doc = new Document();
        
        Path path = Paths.get(docPath);
        fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        
        doc.setName("Stop Payment Request");

        String base64Doc = Base64.encodeToString(fileBytes, false);
        doc.setDocumentBase64(base64Doc);
        doc.setDocumentId("1");
        doc.setFileExtension( "pdf");
        documents.add(doc);

        EnvelopeDefinition envelope1 = new EnvelopeDefinition();      
        envelope1.setDocuments(documents);      

        EnvelopeDocumentsResult result = api.updateDocuments(accountId, envelopeId, envelope1);
        
        retVal = result.getEnvelopeId();        
        return retVal;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```